# how to hide data in options if data same with ng-hide?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I get some problem in my code, for hide data if data same.

this data `1. cars` form JSON

```
[{ _id:1, id_ofcars:10},{ _id:2, id_ofcars:11},{ _id:3, id_ofcars:13},{ _id:4,
id_ofcars:14},{ _id:5, id_ofcars:15}]
```

and data `2.Owners`

```
[{ _id:1, id_ownercars:10},{ _id:2, id_ownercars:11},{ _id:3, id_ownercars:13}]
```

i create in `controller` like this

```
app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {
    function getCarsData() {
          return $http.get('api/cars');
    };
    function getOwnersData() {
         return $http.get('api/owners');
    };
getCarsData().then(function(cek){
    $scope.DataCARS = cek.data;
});
getOwnersData().then(function(cek){
      $scope.DataOWNER = cek.data;
         for (var i=0; i<$scope.DataOWNER.length; i++;){
              $scope.REALOWNER = $scope.DataOWNER[i];
         };
});

}]);
```

and here is a `code html for options Data`

```
<select class="form-control" name="level" id="level" ng-model="_id" ng-click="CheckSurvey(_id)" required>
    <option value="">-- SELECT DATA --</options>
    <option ng-repeat="data in DataCARS " ng-hide="data.id_ofcars ===
REALOWNER.id_ownercars" value="{{data._id}}">{{data.nama}}</option>
              </select>
```

Why after I `loop` and I put the `$scope.REALOWNER.id_ownercars` in `ng-hide`, why he not the hide `id_ofcars`? I just want to hide the data?

Comment: I think it's better to do some pre-processing and get a new array without repetition (where IDs are the same), which is what you want to "hide". You would also need to chain your $http callbacks, since it's asynchronous, so you can do something like: `$http.get(...).then(...).finally(()=>{ $http.get(...).then(...) })`

Comment: hmm, I've tried it lik this 
`$q.all([getCarsData(), getOwnersData()]).then(function (results) {
    var car_data = results[0];
    var owner_data = results[1];
    // you can do your logic here
});`
that same like 
`$http.get(...).then(...).finally(()=>{ $http.get(...).then(...) })` but the options will create the multiple options

Comment: I do not know what to do, mybe i will try get some daata from mongoos query with codition `$not [{id}]`

Answer (score 1):

- 1.- do what Aleksey said (it´s better)
- 2.- Use a sequencial search 
  example:
  https://github.com/CayetanoHerreraLuisRicardo/sequential-Search/blob/master/sequentialSearch.js